# How can I create an UITableView for an Universal App using Xcode 8.3

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, uistoryboard

I am trying to build an universal app which includes a UITableView but for some reason It shows in a different size even after reseting to suggested constraints. I have also tried to pin top, left, right, and bottom but no luck at all. It only works when I use a UITableViewController but I am thinking of using a ViewController and include a Table View inside. Does anybody knows why Auto layout isn't working for me?

[image] Here is the screenshot of how it looks in a new project with different devices!

Comment: It does work with UIViewController, you need to set `Leading, Top, Trailing, Bottom` constraints with respect to the UIView.

Comment: Hi thanks for the quick response. I did exactly the same thing but for some reason it's not showing it in others devices, it still shows the iPhone 7 as the screenshot I posted.

Comment: Have you tried running the project on Simulator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a prototype cell and the view will look rite in the Xcode interface builder - By adding all those constraints the xcode tableview doesn't look rite but it will work rite when you add a prototype cell to it. I think its a bug of Xcode interface builder that the grey area looks smaller but cells are extended.
[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: You are right, I think it might be a glitch for some reason, when I run it on different devices the view changes. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should set Leading, Top, Trailing, Bottom constraints with the `view` of your `UIViewController`. Just like this:

[image]

Comment: Hi thanks for the quick response. I did exactly the same thing but for some reason it's not showing it in others devices, it still shows the iPhone 7 as the screenshot I posted.